# C read strings from a file with complext format

Tags: c, regex, file, io

So I have a file that looks like this:

```
9
$11$ pelle
$2$ pollo
$333$ palla
$41$ alla
$5078$ tta
$6$ tti
$7$ ll
$81$ er
$900$ ere
```

n = 9 is the number of key value pairs I want to read in my program.

so for `key = "11", value = "pelle"` and so on...

```
typedef struct {
    char key[20];
    char value[20];
} Dictionary;

int main() {
    FILE *fin = fopen("../dizionario.txt", "r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }

    int n;
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);

    Dictionary dict[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fscanf(fin, "$%[^$]$ %s\n", dict[i].key, dict[i].value);
    
    fclose(fin);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Key: %s, Value: %s\n", dict[i].key, dict[i].value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have adopted the following approach to read each key-value pair and store them in a dict struct which I believe to be a decent choice. When I print to the console to check the values are all over the place, the output being:

```
Key: , Value:
Key: , Value:
Key: , Value:
Key: , Value:
Key: , Value:
Key: , Value:
Key: , Value: å
Key: <0¶[÷, Value:
Key:    , Value: °
```

I believe the problem to with the format string which I can't seem to get right:

```
"$%[^$]$ %s\n"
```

Comment: You store the read in variables key and value. And expect that there are magicaly copied into dict[i].key and dict[i].value.

Comment: Sorry that was the result of me tinkering with the code trying to find a solution; regarless the format string doesn't seem to work correctly; I have edited the code in the question

Comment: The `scanf()` format is correct. But the first `scanf()` left the carriage return. Use `fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &n);` or add a space at begin of the other scanf (to skip any non printable character before the `$`.

Comment: You should always check the return value from `scanf()`, it tells you how many format specifiers it converted.

Comment: @dalfaB putting whitespace, including `\n`, at the end of a *scanf format string is almost always a bad idea.  Adding an explicit space before `%[…]` is a much better idea.

Comment: Just to throw a different idea out there... you could read the whole thing into memory and write a simple parser (`strchr()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The easiest fix here is add a whitespace   before the 2nd format string so it ignores the trailing newline from the preceding line.
2. Use symbolic constants for your size, and always use maximum field with values when reading strings with `scanf()`.
3. Consider adding a check on `n` to ensure it's sufficiently small (on my system the default stack is 8 MB; or even better use `malloc()` and check that it was successful).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define KEY_LEN 19
#define VALUE_LEN 19
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

typedef struct {
    char key[KEY_LEN + 1];
    char value[VALUE_LEN + 1];
} Dictionary;

int main() {
    FILE *fin = fopen("../dizionario.txt", "r");
    if (!fin) {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }
    int n;
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);
    Dictionary dict[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fscanf(fin, " $%" str(KEY_LEN) "[^$]$ %" str(VALUE_LEN) "s", dict[i].key, dict[i].value);
    fclose(fin);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Key: %s, Value: %s\n", dict[i].key, dict[i].value);
}
```

and corresponding output:

```
Key: 11, Value: pelle
Key: 2, Value: pollo
Key: 333, Value: palla
Key: 41, Value: alla
Key: 5078, Value: tta
Key: 6, Value: tti
Key: 7, Value: ll
Key: 81, Value: er
```

Comment: If that answered your question please click the check mark next to it so we know you are all set.